# Generally: debugging php $_POST

Tags: php

I am wondering what is the best approach for debugging a `$_POST` PHP function, I seem to be losing data and the URL looks like a `$_GET`, I don't want to post the code as I want to learn how to properly debug PHP code if there is somewhat of a recipe on how to do this/some general guidelines I would appreciate them.

In short: After doing some reading for (oh about 8 hours trying to figure this out) I am really lost, what are the do's/don'ts?

Comment: use `print_r($_POST);` to print all post datas

Comment: `$_POST` is a *variable* not a *function*

Answer (score 3):

```
var_dump($_POST);
```

will give you a list of all POST variables.

```
<?php
echo '<pre>';
print_r($_POST);
echo '</pre>';
?>
```

will also work.

Comment: It gave me a empty array with size 0. So I obviously did something wrong in my code hehe. Anyhow I will be sure to note that and use it aswell.

Comment: If it's an empty array, no POST variables exist. Make sure that your form is correct.

Comment: I just double checked, the method is POST, however what is interesting is that dumping _GET gives me all the values I wanted in _POST.

Comment: Are you sure that you've got method="post" and that the rest of your HTML is correct?

Comment: "Should" be yes, the only place where GET is being used is at the top where I am grabbing the ID of the URL.

Comment: Maybe you after form submiting redirect to another page and lose your _POST variable?

Comment: The form is redirecting yes, but I don't think I should lose the data since both have session_start(); in them.

Comment: `session` doesn`t keep _POST and _GET variables, it keeps only `$_SESSION` variable with some session settings variables. I meant than when you submit form to another page with `method="post"`, that page gets _POST data, but maybe in that page you again redirect somewhere?

Comment: I will check more on that, now I really need a break. I can't even tell left from right. Up voting for being helpful anyway, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Please try the following code.

```
print_r($_POST);
```

Answer (score 0):

use `print_r($_POST);` to print all post datas

Answer (score 0):

Check what's inside `$_REQUEST`:

```
var_dump($_REQUEST);
```

This will give you an array representation of you http request, and the method you are using [mostly GET/POST], in case you are using the wrong one.